# woocommerce zip code validation for availability check on single product and also on billing page in shipping form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to restrict customer before they pay if they are not filling right zip code in shipping details on billing page which I have specified in shipping method on Woocommerce settings and also on single product page like amazon`

```
jQuery("form.woocommerce-checkout").on('submit', function() {
                alert('hi');
                var pin_code = jQuery('#shipping_postcode').val();
                alert(pin_code);

                if(pin_code != '')
                {
                    alert(pin_code + 'not blank');

                       jQuery('#error_pin').hide();

                       jQuery('#chkpin_loader').show();

                        jQuery.ajax({
                                url : pincode_check.ajaxurl,
                                type : 'post',
                                data : {
                                action : 'picodecheck_ajax_submit',
                                pin_code : pin_code
                                },
                                success : function( response ) {
                                alert(response)
                                 if(response == 1)
                                 {
                                    alert('match');
                                     return true;

                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                    alert('not match');
                                     return false;                                                                                       

                                 }
                                }
                                }); 

                }
            }); 
`
```

I have added this code by exteding "Woocommerce check pincode/zipcode for shipping" plugin which is used for post code availiblity in single product page,but now I am not able to stop form submission.I want to show error in top like deault error of woocommerce form displays rather submitting the form even if postcode is not match.